# Can I use an USB hub to use the same UPS or printer for multiple computers?

Tags: usb, printer, ups, usb-hub

I'd like to use the same UPS for two small computers. My main problem that I need the battery info for both computers to shut them down when the battery is close to empty. I thought maybe I connect an USB hub to the UPS and connect the two computers to that hub. So the direction would be the opposite of what we have normally. Would it work? If not why?

Comment: You need a UPS with a network connection and software to support multiple computers.

Comment: @John I don't want to buy a new one. I could add a NUT server https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/ to one of the computers, but I am curious if this can be solved with an USB hub.

Comment: UPS cannot work through a HUB . Small units do not support USB this way, and bigger ones have or support network cards. I have an APC unit that I am working from.

Comment: @John Did you try it out or do you have an explanation why?

Comment: I use a connection from my APC to my desktop computer. The APC software only handles one computer and shuts it down.

Comment: @John You are just guessing then.

Comment: No, I have read articles here and there and you cannot use a USB hub to connect UPS boxes to multiple computers. I cannot help you farther and you are on your own on this one.